# changedirector.update(TrackedObject item) throws null reference exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

When looking on the internet for this error i get one hit that is close to the error i am getting. It can be found here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ab51524-e8d5-4eb3-acba-4ff024142e57/nullreferenceexception-in-getupdatecommand-during-submitchanges-call?forum=linqtosql

The solution provided by this person was to rewrite the code, however this is not really an option in this case.

So what happens is that I open a new datacontext connection to our database using linq to sql. Then with or without updating a record a submitchanges is called and the following error is thrown:

```
Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
(no InnerException) 
 StackTrace:    at System.Data.Linq.ChangeDirector.StandardChangeDirector.Update(TrackedObject item)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
  at Brainsch.DLinq.BrainschDataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
```

This exception keeps recurring until the application is restarted. After the application is restarted it does not occur any more.

I found the code part where this error happens(https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Linq/ChangeDirector.cs,f4d313ee41bcda98) and looking at that code gives me many options where the null reference exception occurs.

Can anyone share some light on why this error occurs and how to circumvent it.

Comment: An SQL Command has four different queries 1) Select 2) Delete 3) Update 4) Insert.  A datacontext object when it updates needs all found type commands.  One method is to use a SQL Command Builder which take the Select query and automatically creates the other 3.  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How is this related to the null reference exception i am getting in the standardchangedirector?

Comment: The update command text is null.  It is a little confusing.  When you do an UPDATE to a DataContext object you need to have the four commands (not just the Update command).  When updating a database table you may be inserting new items, deleting existing, or updating existing items,  So the sql command needs all four type instructions (the command text queries).